# 3D Hologram for pc?

Tags: hardware-rec, 3d

I would like to create something similar to what we see on Iron Man move with Jarvis or Jarvas or however you spell his personal AI.

So to put it simple I would like to know if there is an affordable or not hologram that can be used on a PC?

For example we can see something similar here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBuRh1JMO84 I am looking for something that would also allow me to touch it but not very necessary the touch part as I can do it with my webcam sensor.

If there is on that can do 3D instead of just doing what a projector does would be of preference.

Comment: The technology is currently fiction.

Comment: Out of curiosity, [is this your question too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18073625/is-it-possible-to-make-ai-as-smart-as-jarvis-from-iron-man)? I swear I don't have a search filter for `Iron-man` on this site, I swear.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain obviously not, you can clearly see my profile on SO and I do know my away around programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technology to do that does not yet exist. [There are some things that people are working on to make it work](http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/gadgets/high-tech-gadgets/holographic-environment.htm), but nothing today can do what you saw in the movie.

I am afraid what you saw was just movie special effects and there was no image where the actor was in real life, it was added after the fact with special effects.

Comment: I see, well being CES I would think it might be something on the works perhaps but being YT there is also the false-positive factor. I am doing a lot of things with what I have like catching movements and turning it into action (pc commands) however I would really like to have a real hologram, right now I am using a projector and the sensors to work it out.

Comment: That video is not a hologram, it looks like they are ussing the [Pepper's Ghost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pepper%27s_Ghost) style projection, you can't reach in or through it like you saw in the movie, notice in the CES video how there is glass encased on all sides. A rap tour did a similar thing [with a projection of 2pac](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGbrFmPBV0Y) recently.